# Meteor get unique items from a collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor, distinct, meteor-blaze

I have a collection `Files` which contain items with a `userId`. I want a unique array with all `userId`s in the collection.

Here my first approach (code from here: [LINK](https://forums.meteor.com/t/unique-values-of-a-specific-field-in-the-collection/19975/4))

**Server Method**

```
'uniqUser': function(){
  const distinct = Meteor.wrapAsync(Files.rawCollection().distinct,Files.rawCollection());
  const result = distinct('userId');
  console.log(result)
  return result
}
```

**Client Call**

```
uniqUser(){
  Meteor.call('uniqUser', function(err, data) {
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  });
}
```

the `console.log` looks good:
[image]

**but my view show nothing!? also no errors...**

```
uniqUser:
{{#each uniqUser}}
  <p>{{this}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: your `uniqUser` should be a key in object like `{ uniqUser: ["fsdfd", "ooop"]}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to use `meteor-reactive-method` [LINK](https://github.com/stubailo/meteor-reactive-method):

```
  uniqUser() {
     return ReactiveMethod.call("uniqUser");
  }
```

and eveything is fine!